# QProcess::Crashed. Avoiding Windows 10 crash message of external program

Tags: c++, qt, visual-c++, qprocess, qtcore

Suppose that we want to run external command line application, for example "dir" and suppose that it crashes:

```
namespace util
{

        bool execChildProcess(const std::string & cmd,  std::string & cmdOutput)
        {
           QProcess process;
           QString qStrCmd = QString::fromStdString(cmd);
           process.start(qStrCmd);

           if(process.exitStatus() == QProcess::Crashed )
           {
               std::cout<<"QProcess::Crashed"<<std::endl;
               process.kill();
           }

           if(process.waitForFinished() && process.exitStatus() == QProcess::NormalExit )
           {
               QString output(process.readAllStandardOutput());
               cmdOutput = output.toStdString();
               std::cout<<"Result: "<<cmdOutput<<std::endl;
               return true;
           }
           else
           {
                   switch(process.error())
                   {
                    case QProcess::FailedToStart :
                        std::cout<<"QProcess::FailedToStart"<<std::endl;
                        break ;
                    case QProcess::Crashed :
                        std::cout<<"QProcess::Crashed"<<std::endl;
                        break ;
                    case QProcess::Timedout:
                        std::cout<<"QProcess::Timedout"<<std::endl;
                        break ;
                    case QProcess::WriteError:
                        std::cout<<"QProcess::WriteError"<<std::endl;
                        break ;
                    case QProcess::ReadError:
                        std::cout<<"QProcess::ReadError"<<std::endl;
                        break ;
                    case QProcess::UnknownError:
                        std::cout<<"QProcess::UnknownError"<<std::endl;
                        break ;
                    }
                    process.kill();
           }
           return false;
        }
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
        std::string output;
        bool res = util::execChildProcess("dir", output);
}
```

the crash is catched after we close this message:

[image]

After the message is closed the code kill the process but not before.

How we can avoid this message with QProcess(I don't know if it also happen in ubuntu but i would like a cross-platform solution in case it also happen in ubuntu).

Answer (score 0):

Call `SetErrorMode(SEM_NOGPFAULTERRORBOX)` in your process; the error mode is inherited by the child processes. You can revert it right after you start the process:

```
QProcess process;
...
auto errMode = GetErrorMode();
SetErrorMode(errMode | SEM_NOGPFAULTERRORBOX);
connect(&process, &QProcess::stateChanged, [errMode](QProcess::ProcessState state) { if (state != QProcess::Starting) SetErrorMode(errMode); });
process.start();
...
```

You could also execute `SetErrorMode(SEM_NOGPFAULTERRORBOX)` in the target process. For this, you could create a `.DLL` that includes this call, and [inject it into the target process](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25521327/1329652).

The target process handle can be obtained as follows:

```
HANDLE getHandle(const QProcess *process) {
  auto pid = process->processId();
  return pid->hProcess;
}
```

Comment: All [Solutions here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2284138/disable-debug-prompt-on-application-crash) used a variant of registry approach including that which mentioned  `SetErrorMode` solution, Do you think the registry approach solution is aggressive ?

Answer (score -1):

Its possible to exclude an application from automatic debugging under windows, thus getting away from the debugging popup.

Under windows edit registry key:

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows
>   NT\CurrentVersion\AeDebug

Add a `REG_DWORD` value to the `AutoExclusionList` subkey, where the name is the name of the executable file and the value is 1.

You don't have to do that manually in your app, you could use Qt `QSettings` like this:

```
QSettings settings("HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AeDebug",
QSettings::NativeFormat);
auto key = settings.childKeys().at(x);
```

Then you can use `QSettings::setValue` to set the key to 1.

Complete information and reference under MSDN pages [Configuring Automatic Debugging](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb204634(v=vs.85).aspx)

For Ubuntu, it should be controlled, given that the process is killed.

Comment: I edited with regedit command line. Do i need to restart windows?, I only close the terminal. The external program is a portable binary file .exe and it was not installed in the system through a windows wizard. It does not work.

Comment: No need to restart I suppose, but I am not sure in case its not installed with wizard.

Answer (score -1):

As [Mohammad Kanan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7478455/mohammad-kanan) has pointed out, we can disable the Error Dialog in the edit registry key, but in this case for Windows 10 pro it is under:

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Windows Error Reporting

Find the value named

> DontShowUI

or add a new DWORD value with this name if it doesn't exist. The default value of this key is 0. Double click it to edit, change the value to 1 and save